# How to find Coefficient Correlation of two rows in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have below pyspark dataframe

```
stat        col_A    col_B       col_C     col_D   
count        14       14          14 14      14
Actual        4       4001       160987      49  
Regression    3       3657       131225      38
```

I want to find **Coefficient Correlation ** of row ***Actual*** and ***Regression***. And add ans as a new row **CV**.

```
stat        col_A    col_B       col_C     col_D   
count        14       14          14 14      14
Actual        4       4001       160987      49  
Regression    3       3657       131225      38  
CV
```

In Spark documentation we can apply **corr(col1, col2, method=None)** method. But it's on the column. But in my case, I want it on row.
In pandas I have done like this

```
(df1.loc[['Actual','Regression']].std(axis = 0, ddof=0,skipna = True))/(df1.loc[['Actual','Regression']].mean(axis = 0))*100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = df.union(
    df.filter("stat in ('Actual', 'Regression')")
      .select(
          F.lit('CV').alias('stat'), 
          *[(F.stddev_pop(c) / F.mean(c) * 100).alias(c) for c in df.columns[1:]]
      )
)

result.show()
+----------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|      stat|             col_A|            col_B|             col_C|             col_D|
+----------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|     count|              14.0|             14.0|              14.0|              14.0|
|    Actual|               4.0|           4001.0|          160987.0|              49.0|
|Regression|               3.0|           3657.0|          131225.0|              38.0|
|        CV|14.285714285714285|4.492034473752938|10.185071112753755|12.643678160919542|
+----------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

which agrees with your expected output:

```
(df1.loc[['Actual','Regression']].std(axis = 0, ddof=0,skipna = True))/(df1.loc[['Actual','Regression']].mean(axis = 0))*100
col_A    14.285714
col_B     4.492034
col_C    10.185071
col_D    12.643678
```